# Calculating distance between element and subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $L=\{(\xi_j)\in \ell_1 \ \colon \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{j}{j+1}\xi_j=0\}$, which is a subspace in $\ell_1$. I want to find 
$$d(e_1,L)=\inf\{\|e_1-y\|\ \colon y\in L\},$$
where $e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots)$. Intuition says that it should be $\frac12$, but any ideas on how to prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},...) \in \ell_\infty$. Since $L = \ker f$, and by definition of operator norms, we have for all $y \in L$ that $||f||_\infty ||e_1 - y||_1 \geq$  $|f(e_1 - y)| = \frac{1}{2}$. Since $||f||_\infty = 1$, this implies $dist(e_1,L) \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

To see that in fact $dist(e_1,L) = \frac{1}{2}$ consider the sequence $y_n = e_1 -\frac{n+1}{2n}e_n$: We have $y_n \in L$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||e_1 - y_n||_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That doesn't give us equality. We also can't find an element, such that $\|e_1-y\|=\frac12$.

Comment: I'm working at it. I thought finding that element was the intuition the OP mentioned. Not so sure now.

Comment: I fixed it. The minimum is not attained but there is a minimising sequence.

Comment: Is there a clever proof that there are no elemnets $y\in L$, such that $\|e_1-y\|=\frac12$?

Comment: You can show this by direct calculation: If $||e_1-y||=\frac{1}{2}$, which is minimal, then $y=(a_1,-a_2,-a_3,-a_4,...)$ with all $a_i \geq 0$ and $a_1 \leq 1$. Let's call $\sum_{j=2} a_j = t_2$. Then $\frac{1}{2} = 1-a_1 + t_2$ so that $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}+t_2$. Also, $\frac{1}{2} a_1 = \frac{2}{3} a_2 + \frac{3}{4} a_3 ...$. Substitute this into the previous equation and rearrange to get $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3} a_2 + \frac{2}{4} a_3 + \frac{3}{5} a_4 + ... < t_2$. But if $\frac{1}{2} < t_2$ then $a_1>1$, which contradicts the required minimality.